# Operator Overloading assignment with templates - C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm new here (this is actually my first question here) and looking for some help with a program I'm working on for my Data Structures class.

It is about Operator overloading of = , + and <<.

right now, I'm using a .cpp file that has the function template, including the declarations and definitions:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

template <class t_type>    
class TLIST {
public:
    TLIST();
    TLIST(const TLIST<t_type> &);
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    int Search(t_type);
    TLIST<t_type> & TLIST<t_type>::operator+(const t_type &rhs);
    void Remove(const t_type);

    // TLIST<t_type> & operator=(const TLIST<t_type> &);
    // friend operator<<(ostream &, TLIST<t_type> &);

    void Double_Size();

    /*other functions you may want to implement*/
private:
    t_type *DB;
    int count;
    int capacity;
    /*additonal state variables you may wish add*/
};
```

In my other .cpp file , I included the previous file and have this following code:

```
TLIST<char> Char_List,TempChar1, TempChar2;

Char_List + 'W' + 'E' + 'L' + 'C' + 'O' + 'M' + 'E'; // chaining
```

Now, I'm trying to overload the "+" operator. I am at a point where I asked the professor if my declaration is correct and he told me it is but I'm missing something inside the definition:

```
template <class t_type>
TLIST<t_type> & TLIST<t_type>::operator+(const t_type &rhs)

{
    TLIST <t_type> lhs;
    lhs += rhs;
    return *this;
}
```

I keep getting this error :

```
 Error  1   error C2676: binary '+=' : 'TLIST' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  c:\users\negri\dropbox\visual studio\projects\assignment 1 (tlist2)\assignment 1 (tlist2)\tlist.cpp 53  1   Assignment 1 (TLIST2)
```

which is understandable, since I'm trying to have a template of chars on lhs and just a char on rhs (correct me if I'm wrong).

How should I go ahead and fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: First, `operator +` should be a friend function for `class TLIST`; Second, `operator +=` should be defined

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with that `operator+`:

```
template <class t_type>
TLIST<t_type> & TLIST<t_type>::operator+(const t_type &rhs)
{
    TLIST <t_type> lhs;
    lhs += rhs;
    return *this;
}
```

The first thing is that you are returning a *reference*, but creating a variable inside the function then modifying it and finally returning a reference to `this` (on which you have not applied any operation!!). Your implementation is an expensive version of:

```
return *this;
```

Then the definition of addition is *wrong*, you create a `TLIST` using the default constructor, and then attempt to add the argument. This is not *adding* to *this* object, but to an empty `TLIST`!.

Then there is the fact that your code depends on `operator+=`, but that operator does not seem to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `lhs += rhs;` you expect the compiler to know what `+=` means. However, you did not define the operator `+=`, so the compiler doesn't know how to implement it. One solution is to define the `operator+=` first and keep the `operator+` as it is.